# Vuetify - How to set background color

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify with the Light theme. By default this sets the background of the main content to a light grey. I need it to be white.

I'd like to override this by modifying the stylus variables, but I can't seem to figure out which variable sets the background color.

I followed all the steps in the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme), and I can change the font throughout the app by setting `$body-font-family = 'Open Sans'` in my main.styl file (so I know I have the webpack build set up correctly)

I have tried `$body-bg-light = '#fff'` in my main.styl, but that doesn't seem to change anything at all. If I set `$material-light.background = '#fff'` I get an error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have the right approach. You only need to import vuetify's theme file first so that the `material-light` variable is defined:

```css
// main.styl

@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/theme.styl'

$material-light.background = #fff

@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main.styl'
```

---

### Vuetify 2.0 update

Vuetify switched to SASS in 2.0, so the syntax is slightly different. Follow [the guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables) to set up sass-loader properly, then add this to your variables.scss file:

```css
$material-light: (
  'background': #fff
);
```

The theme and main imports are no longer needed, and maps are merged by vuetify so you only have to define keys you want to change.

Comment: This works... Thanks! https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme#stylus-guide

Comment: This works, any idea how to set the primary, secondary, accent colors through stylus?

Comment: Using vue-cli, all I needed to do was create src/styles/variables.scss and add the code shown under Vuetify 2.0 update and it worked a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 96):

With Vuetify 2.0, I would like to propose my solution:

[Vuetifty Theme Referance](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme)

Follow the documentation as usual with setting up custom theming, except add another variable (background in my case).

```javascript
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: colors.purple,
        secondary: colors.grey.darken1,
        accent: colors.shades.black,
        error: colors.red.accent3,
        background: colors.indigo.lighten5, // Not automatically applied
        ...
      },
      dark: {
        primary: colors.blue.lighten3, 
        background: colors.indigo.base, // If not using lighten/darken, use base to return hex
        ...
      },
    },
  },
})
```

But we are not done! The `background` variable doesn't cut it. We need to rig `v-app` to toggle the light/dark backgrounds.

```vue
<template>
  <v-app id="main" :style="{background: $vuetify.theme.themes[theme].background}">
    <v-content>
        Stuff :)
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  computed:{
    theme(){
      return (this.$vuetify.theme.dark) ? 'dark' : 'light'
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: real nice. Worked for me using: ```<v-app :style="{background: $vuetify.theme.themes.dark.background}">```

Comment: I used a computed theme to be able to have a different background color for light and dark themes. If you force dark theme, just use dark :)

Comment: brilliant! by far simplest solution i saw in about an hour of searching / experimenting

Comment: should be the accepted answer, also why is this so hard to override styling

Comment: It might apply the background color for the container, but not for the sub components.

Comment: @AbdelillahAissani True, but for all other components, you can change the background in a similar manner.

Answer (score 21):

### To override the dark theme background color

Personally, I find this a very clean way.
Set your background color in vuetify.js like so:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
    themes: {
      dark: {
        background: '#292930',
      },
    },
      dark: true,
  },
});
```

Then add this to your css file (eg. "app.css", in the project root):

```
.v-application {
    background-color: var(--v-background-base) !important;
}
```

And in your App.Vue, simply import the css file:

```
import styles from './app.css'
```

Comment: Incredible answer, but I've got to use a scss file because it didn't recognize `var(--v-background-base)`.

Comment: @EduardoJiménez make sure you also set `themes: light: { ... }` if you use the light theme, and check you have `options: { customProperties: true }` which generates the CSS variables - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#custom-properties

Comment: This works for me, but do you mind to explain how this line `var(--v-background-base)` works?

Comment: Ah - ok, I found the documentation for this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#custom-properties (for vuetify 2.x)

Answer (score 13):

To change the background colour simply...

```html
<v-app class="white">
```

for text color

```html
<v-app class="grey--text text--darken-2">
```

Comment: Other colours than white work this way but for a white background you have to use `<v-app class="shades white">`. See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#material-colors

Answer (score 12):

There is another solution:

**In vuetify.js:**

```
export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: '#e20074',
                secondary: '#6c757d',
                accent: '#3ea2fb',
                error: '#dc3545',
                petrol: '#17a499',
                background: '#fff',
            }
        },
        options: {
            customProperties: true
        },
    },
})
```

**In App.vue:**

```
<v-app id="app">
...
</app>

<style>
#app {
    background-color: var(--v-background-base);
}
</style>
```

Details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285278/506764

Comment: This is the simplest solution

Answer (score 5):

On the main container, the class setting the default light grey color as background color is `.application.theme--light` (or dark, depending on what you're using).

Within vuetify, this color is set up in `src/stylus/settings/_theme.styl` :

```
$material-light := {
  status-bar: {
    regular: #E0E0E0,
    lights-out: rgba(#fff, .7)
  },
  app-bar: #F5F5F5,
  background: #FAFAFA, // here
  cards: #FFFFFF,
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find any easy way to override the background color specifically (since the color is defined directly) so I ended up overriding the whole `material-light` property i.e copy-pasting the default code and setting the background color I wanted.

Comment: I did the same. Let me know if you find a way to only overwrite a single attribute .

Comment: Where did you place the override? If I put it before the stylus import I got errors and if I place it after the import, the override does not work. Thanks

Comment: And how could this be done when working with a-la-carte components? They directly import their styles from the theme defined in the library...

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a short article for Vetify.js 2 and Nuxt.js combining above solutions: [Changing Background Color in Vuetify.js and Nuxt.js](https://medium.com/@jareklipski/changing-background-color-in-vuetify-js-and-nuxt-js-b4222cfa547e) - I thought someone might find it interesting.

Basically the idea is to use custom background color:

```
vuetify: {
  customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
  treeShake: true,
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true
    },
    dark: true,
    themes: {
      dark: {
        background: '#00a86b'
      },
      light: {
        background: '#d0f0c0'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And apply it in `variables.scss`:

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
$material-light: map-merge($material-light, (
  'background': var(--v-background-base, map-get($material-light, 'background')) !important,
));
$material-dark: map-merge($material-dark, (
  'background': var(--v-background-base, map-get($material-dark, 'background')) !important,
));
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at **[Vuetify Themes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme)**, where you could do something like:

```html
<v-app dark>
...
</v-app>
```

To apply a dark theme, for instance. This is the preferred way as it also modifies all "standard colors" that go with vuetify (such as danger, primary, etc.).

If you need to be quick and dirty, you can also **apply `class`es or `style`s to the `<v-app>`**:

```html
<v-app style="
  background: #3A1C71;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FFAF7B, #D76D77, #3A1C71);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFAF7B, #D76D77, #3A1C71);
">
```

Which can be used in conjunction with the dark theme ([source](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-change-background-color-in-vuetify/37905/2)).

Answer (score 2):

Direct injecting of css code, it can be solved. Inspect the code on your browser and find out the class or id name. Go to your component, in style section write your code as for example: I have inspected the code and find out the class name, class name is '.v-picker_body' inside the class there is a div. i need to change the div's background color. So here it is-

```
<style>
 .v-picker__body > div{
    background-color: #F44336;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The v-app tag contains an attribute 'id="app"' by default. To change the styling:

```
<style>
#app {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to change the background was that:

Set the background color in your **/src/plugins/vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
  theme: {
    dark: true,
    themes: {
      dark: {
        background: colors.grey.darken4,
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And then bind it to your v-app component.

```
<v-app v-bind:style="{ background: $vuetify.theme.themes.dark.background}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change ***v-app*** Style

```
 <v-app style="background-color:black; color:white">
        
 </v-app>
```

Same in main style file

*main.css*

`body { background-color: black; color: white }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the light/dark theme default background color using the method above, however it does not work!!! here is what I did

add new style file under `./src/scss/main.scss`

```
// src/scss/main.scss
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass'
$new-colors: (
    'app-bar': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
    'background': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
    'cards': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
    'bg-color': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
    'fg-color': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
    'text-color': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
    'buttons': (
      'disabled': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
      'focused': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
      'focused-alt': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
      'pressed': map-get($red, 'lighten-4') !important,
    ),
);
$material-light: map-merge($material-light, $new-colors);
$material-dark: map-merge($material-dark, $new-colors);
@debug $material-light;

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass';
@import '~vuetify/src/components/VBtn/_variables.scss';
```

Then I imported this file from `./src/main.js` like this:

```
// ./src/main.js 
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import './scss/main.scss';

new Vue({
    vuetify,
    beforeCreate() {
        console.log('Before our APP is created');
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Our APP is being mounted now.');
    },
    render: function(h) {
        return h(App);
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

I am using `vue 2.6.7` and `vuetify 2.1.7`

Answer (score 0):

On a `root` level of a component, to have all page/route/view in the same color:

```
<template>
  <div style="background-color: #333">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Here, the `root` element for a component that's `<div>`, however you can have almost any you'd like to. It works on `<section>`, `<v-layout>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue with the current `vuetify v2.5.5`, simply add this line to your `variable.scss` file:

```
$material-light: ( 'background': #e5e5e5 );
```

Replace `#e5e5e5` with your desired color.