# vuetify: how to set the window background color?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a small vuetify 2.x app that displays a list with the dark theme.

When I scroll beyond the end of the list (top or bottom) I see a white zone appearing for a second.

Is it possible to set the window background color to black, or the same as the dark theme background color, so that I don't have this white zone showing up when I scroll beyond the end of the page ?

I tested without success the answer to the question [vuetify how to set background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243769/vuetify-how-to-set-background-color).

**Solution**: setting `<body style="background-color:black;">` in the `public/index.html` fie fixed the problem. Now it's just a matter of finding the color matching the dark background of vuetify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify changes the background color of `v-app` based on dark mode.

You could use a watcher on Vuetify's dark mode (`$vuetify.theme.isDark`) that sets the `body`'s background color to match that of the `v-app`:

1. Add a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to the `v-app` component (named "app"):

   ```html
   <v-app ref="app">
   ```
2. Add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on Vuetify's `$vuetify.theme.isDark` property that copies the `v-app`'s background color to the body. The `v-app`'s background color takes effect in the next render cycle, so query it in [`$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick):

   ```js
   export default {
     watch: {
       '$vuetify.theme.isDark'() {
         this.$nextTick(() => {
           const rootStyles = window.getComputedStyle(this.$refs.app.$el)
           document.body.style.backgroundColor = rootStyles.backgroundColor
         })
       }
     }
   }
   ```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vuetify-overscroll-color)

[image: screencast]