# How to use vuetify theme variables in styles

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I want to use the variables defined in my vuetify theme in the style portion of my vue files. Its not mentioned on the docs and can't seem to find an answer anywahere, does anyone know how to do this?

e.g.

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#3f51b5',
  }
})
```

now in my Home component I want to do:

```
<template>
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</template>

<styles>
    h1{
        color:$primary; #from the vuetify theme
    }  
</styles>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom theming in Vuetify and pass color variables to components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280990/using-custom-theming-in-vuetify-and-pass-color-variables-to-components)

Comment: The answers on the other question are more work arounds than official solutions, which is ideally what i want. Though if there isn't one then I guess the work around will have to do.

Comment: > `The answers on the other question are more work arounds than official solutions,` One of the answers quotes official statement about this issue. And reply on that answer is by one of the Vuetify devs. So it doesn't negate the fact that this is a duplicate question (at least I don't see any difference?). I.e. afaics the official "solution" is a "workaround", lol.

Comment: The official answer was referring to stylus, not scss - though don't know if the same applies

Comment: Good point, however I think the same applies because the workaround uses CSS, but I presume you could use stylus as well. See this https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/4774

Comment: I have updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285278/1981247), found docs with that regard, check it out!

Answer (score 3):

U can use:

```css
<style scoped>
  .something {
    color:            var(--v-primary-base);
    background-color: var(--v-accent-lighten2);
  }
</style>
```

From this list:

```css
  --v-anchor-base: #c42742;
  --v-primary-base: #c42742;
  --v-primary-lighten5: #2c0447;
  --v-primary-lighten4: #cfa854;
  --v-primary-lighten3: #dd88cc;
  --v-primary-lighten2: #b49921;
  --v-primary-lighten1: #f899c7;
  --v-primary-darken1: #0169dc;
  --v-primary-darken2: #c28fd0;
  --v-primary-darken3: #fbe002;
  --v-primary-darken4: #33303a;
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285278/1084004 for full details, `customProperties: true` might need to be set

Answer (score 0):

Update for Vuetify 3 (on top [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280990/using-custom-theming-in-vuetify-and-pass-color-variables-to-components/48285278#48285278)):

The [Upgrade Guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#setup) makes brief mention of changes, but doesn't go into detail. Instead of:

```scss
<style scoped>
  .something {
    color:            var(--v-primary-base);
    background-color: var(--v-accent-lighten2);
  }
</style>
```

You'll now do this:

```scss
<style scoped>
  .something {
    color:            rgb(var(--v-theme-primary));
    background-color: rgba(var(--v-theme-primary), 0.3);
  }
</style>
```

As of this writing, the available options are listed in the [vuetify theme spec test file](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/e66f65e727b29a61524f4ad90a7eb479dcfb96c4/packages/vuetify/src/composables/__tests__/__snapshots__/theme.spec.ts.snap#L20).