# Using Vuetify classes within SASS

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I would like to use some of the existing Vuetify classes in my own `sass` file, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I have a Vue-CLI3 project with the latest Vue/Vuetify, and have the following code:

`main.sass`

```css
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass'

.myTest
  @extend .mr-1
  @extend .shrink
```

I also have the `vue.config.js` setup to correctly reference the `sass`/`scss` files:

```js
export default {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "path/to/main.sass"`
      },
      scss: {
        data: `@import "path/to/main.scss";`
      },
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile, I get `The target selector was not found`, and it points to `.mr-1` and `.shrink`.  Am I doing this incorrectly?

All other CSS in my `main.sass` file works as expected, so I believe the wiring is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the [spacing helper classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/) (including `.mr-1`) are only found when importing `vuetify/src/styles/main.sass` instead of `styles.sass`. The `.shrink` class is found in `vuetify/src/components/VGrid/_grid.sass`.

So your `main.sass` should look like this:

```css
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass'
@import '~vuetify/src/components/VGrid/_grid.sass' // for .shrink

.myTest
  @extend .mr-1
  @extend .shrink
```

#### `sass-loader` config

The original question is probably using an older version of `sass-loader`, given the `sass.data` config. If using version 8 or newer, the loader option is `sass.additionalData`:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        // sass-loader >= 8
        additionalData: `@import "~@/path/to/main.sass"`

        // sass-loader < 8
        data: `@import "~@/path/to/main.sass"`
      }
    }
  },
}
```

#### Prepending global styles

With the `sass-loader` config above, importing `vuetify/src/styles/main.sass` in your project's root `main.sass` (as done in the original question) causes an error. The workaround is to copy the contents of Vuetify's `main.sass` into your own. However, if your app uses any Vuetify components, you'll see the same error for `_grid.sass`, and the same workaround applies:

```css
// @import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass' ❌ SassError: This file is already being loaded.
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/tools/_index'
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index'
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/generic/_index'
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/elements/_index'
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/utilities/_index'

// @import '~vuetify/src/components/VGrid/_grid.sass' ❌ SassError: This file is already being loaded.
.shrink
  flex-grow: 0 !important
  flex-shrink: 1 !important

.myTest
  @extend .mr-1
  @extend .shrink
```

This approach gets unwieldy the more you need to extend the component-specific styles.

Also, since this prepends the contents of your `main.sass` to all Sass entry points, you may notice a significant delay in build/dev times (hampering developer experience), and a sizable vendor CSS chunk in your build output.

#### Better alternatives

You could avoid the caveats above by importing your `main.sass` in `main.js`:

```js
import '@/main.sass'
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/extending-vuetify-styles-forked-61qkn?file=/src/main.js:85-107)

On the other hand, if you only need these styles in a specific component, use local styles instead:

```html
<script>
import '@/main.sass'
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/extending-vuetify-styles-forked-ssx17?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue)

```html
<!-- or -->
<style lang="sass">
@import '~@/main.sass'
</style>
```

[demo 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/extending-vuetify-styles-forked-b1o8n?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue)

```html
<!-- or -->
<style lang="sass">
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass'
@import '~vuetify/src/components/VGrid/_grid.sass' // for .shrink

.myTest
  @extend .mr-1
  @extend .shrink
</style>
```

[demo 4](https://codesandbox.io/s/extending-vuetify-styles-forked-tymp5?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Also this issue is mentioned at vuetify repo https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12646

Comment: @LastM4N I ran some tests to verify the duplicate styles problem mentioned in the GitHub issue, and could not reproduce. My tests show *no* duplicate Vuetify classes in the output. It seems the CSS minification properly eliminates the duplicate styles even if `main.sass` were imported in several components, and even with scoped styles (tested with Vue CLI 5.0.0-alpha.4).

Answer (score 0):

So, I achieved to do it thanks to Vue CLI and some documentation. Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/kissu/so-vuetify-access-variables), here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-access-variables-2cczq?file=/src/plugins/vuetify.js).

Basically, the setting was as follows:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: { customProperties: true }, // interesting part
  },
})
```

I'm not sure about the `vue.config.js` nor the `webpack.config.js` configurations since it also depends on your versions of `node-sass` and `sass-loader` but you said that you handled it well by yourself, so no big worries I guess.

I made the example in the `App.vue` file in which I wrote
`<div id="priority" class="medium">hello, this is working !</div>`

- There is a `global.sass` file that will target it's `div` tag and apply `color: var(--v-warning-base)`.
- There is a `global.scss` file that will target it's `.medium` class and apply `color: var(--v-accent-base)`.
- Finally, the component itself will target it's `#priority` id and apply `color: var(--v-error-base)`.

[image]

I found the answer thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285278/8816585), give it a thumbs up too !

Comment: Hello @kissu, I'm not quite sure that you answered the question. Can you please provide a sandbox which has css classes using inside vuetify's classes? For example, some vuetify classes are for spacing mr-1 , pa-5. Can you please include those in css classes in order to close the bounty?