# Expose theme colors to css variables in vuetify not working

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I enabled custom properties:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    options: {
        customProperties: true
    }
});
```

and trying to use through CSS variable :

```css
<style>
    .custom{
        color:var(--v-primary-base);
    }
</style>
```

this is `vuetify.js` file where I am setting theme :

```js
export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                background: '#FFFFFF',
                primary: '#25316A',
                secondary: '#b0bec5',
                accent: '#25316A',
                error: '#E86674',
                orange: '#FF7A0D',
                golden: '#A68C59',
                badge: '#F5528C',
                customPrimary: '#085294',
            },
            dark: {
                primary: '#085294',
            }
        },
    },
})
```

None of the theme colors are accessible through variables. I tried many ways but hasn't worked and no error thrown. Any one can please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280990/using-custom-theming-in-vuetify-and-pass-color-variables-to-components

Comment: @AnnKilzer No, it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to pass the `options` property to the `Vuetify` instance instead, **not** in the `use` function.

From the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#custom-properties):

```js
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
    // ...
  },
})
```

Comment: Vuetify's variables stop working at this point, why is that? you cant use variables.scss for example and define $stepper-header-height: or something .. (without customProperties, this works)

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the options in vuetify file but you have used it in wrong place like this...

```
export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
    theme: {
        options: {
            customProperties: true,
        },
        themes: {
            light: {
                background: '#FFFFFF',
                primary: '#25316A',
                secondary: '#b0bec5',
                accent: '#25316A',
                error: '#E86674',
                orange: '#FF7A0D',
                golden: '#A68C59',
                badge: '#F5528C',
                customPrimary: '#085294',
            },
            dark: {
                primary: '#085294',
            }
        },
    },
})
```

After that when you want to use your custom CSS variable as you made it you have to use it like this..

```
<style>
    .custom{
        color:var(--v-golden-base);
    }
</style>
```

Here base is a default and I showed for the golden variable but You can use any of them.

Comment: do you know why color: var(--v-info-lighten2) works? but var(--v-red-lighten2) doesnt?

Comment: You  got your answer?

Comment: god, i dont remember, no longer working with vue. i guess you were both right, i put it in the wrong place..

Comment: This doesen't work. `customProperties` has to be set in `theme` NOT `themes`

Comment: It worked in my project and my project is now up and running! I don't know why is not working in yours!