# Control the color of a svg with vuetify / Vue.js

Tags: svg, colors, themes, vuetify.js, fill

The colors get controlled by vuetify, there is a dark and light theme. How can I change the color of a svg depending on the active theme?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="blue"
```

Fill only works for colors but not with the usual theme properties as "primary" "error" and so on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Enabling customProperties in your vuetify.js-file will allow you to read the theme colors inside components as css variables.

Apply a css-class to your svg element and target the fill attribute in the css, for example:

```
<rect
class="fillClass"
..
/>

<style scoped>
.fillClass {
fill: var(--v-error-base);
}
</style>
```

See this thread and particulary the answer from april 21 for more info:

[Using custom theming in Vuetify and pass color variables to components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280990/using-custom-theming-in-vuetify-and-pass-color-variables-to-components)